# What formula could I use to represent this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I have following series -

$$1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, \dots$$

How can I mathematically represent this series? I can't represent it as AP as `d` is not constant. I couldn't represent it as GP either.

Comment: You might want to be careful about the difference between series and sequences. A sequence is an ordered list of objects and a series is the sum of terms of a sequence. That is, you might want to make clear whether you are talking about a closed form for the sum of the first $n$ terms (the sum is obviously not convergent) or a closed form for term $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$-th term  $=1 + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Method of difference.

Comment: How did you arrive at this formula? What kind of series is this? Could you give me the name or point me to some resource to learn more about it?

Comment: AFAIK This does have any name as in it is a random series, there are lots of series like this. We use a method called "Method of difference" to solve them. Just Google it out or you can refer to any good reference book.

Comment: Check out http://www.purplemath.com/modules/nextnumb.htm , where they work out  2, 5, 10, 17, 26,....

Answer (score 4):

$1+0=1$

$1+1=2$

$2+2=4$

$4+3=7$

$7+4=11$

$11+5=16$

$16+6=22$

$22+7=29$

$29+8=37$

$37+9=46$

$46+10=56$

...............

...............

...............

...............
Do you see the pattern now?

Can you see how you can write this as a recurrence?

See [**Method of Differences**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_finite_differences).

Regards -A

Comment: I am not sure the OP got it, was trying to guide them so they could solve it themselves. Thanks!